# How can I alloww access with HTTPS to a website in a google cloud server?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, https

I have a website hosted on google cloud and I want to allow access via https (now only allows http).

I have added my ssl certificate and private key to the server where I keep my website.

- It's an ubuntu server
- I put the certificate in `/etc/ssl/certs/` and the private key in `/etc/ssl/private/`
- Changed the names of the new certificates in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

Also I added this lines to `.htaccess` to allow https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

I have also created an instance group and a load balancer with my SSL certificate on Google cloud, but when I try to access my website via https I get

> Cannot reach this website
>
> The page **ip of my server** has refused the connection.

Does anyone know why I can't access via https? Did I forget something?

Comment: Which google cloud service are you using to host your site?

Comment: TLS configuration must be done only at Load Balancer level. Because the traffic is proxied, the TLS information are not forwarded to the backends.